# google graph does not work with jquery button function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, button, google-visualization

As you may see below, I created the function getChart();
It works when called by itself, but does not display the chart when I wrap it into $(document).ready(function(){...});
I also attached the file..
Any help is highly valued and appreciated.. thanx..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Google Visualization API Sample</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function getChart(){
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    function drawVisualization() {
       // Populate the data table.

        var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45],
           ['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15]
        // Treat first row as data as well.
        ], true);   

        // Draw the chart.
        var chart = new     google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
        chart.draw(dataTable, {legend:'none', width:600, height:400});
    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#idbutton').click(function(){
            getChart();
        });
    });


  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="idbutton" type="button" value="button" />
<div id="visualization"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does `getChart()` return a string? Do `alert(getChart());` and tell us the output.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd guess "this" isn't pointing where you want it to, but to be honest, there's not much code to go by here.

Comment: I attached the code above.. Thanks..

Comment: When I run this code and debug it (shift+ctrl+j), I see that the body tag disappears..

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach it to the window object.
Something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.getChart = function() { //Code of getChart here };
});
```

And call it with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#idbutton').click(function(){
        window.getChart();
    });
});
```

Note: I did not test it.

Comment: what confuses me is that when i call the getChart(); function on its own it works and i can display the chart.. But what i really need is to attach that function to an event listener.. basically, I got a table of 101 stocks, and I would like to be able to display the respective chart dynamically when i click on a row.. The button is just for testing purposes. I would very much wellcome other suggestions..

Comment: That's weird. Did you include the reference to jquery when you tested it without using jquery functions?